# How to get the empty entries from a Dictionary in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have some dictionary I have defined which might have values that are empty. Is there a quick way to check to see if any of my key value pairs contain empty entries?

```
julia> a = Dict(1=>[1,2], 4=>[3,4], 6=>[])
Dict{Int64, Vector{T} where T} with 3 entries:
  4 => [3, 4]
  6 => Any[]
  1 => [1, 2]
```

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wanted a quick way thus I would recommend:

```
findall(isempty, a)
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible concise solution it to use a comprehension and the [`isempty`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.isempty) function which will check this for you as follows:

```
julia> [k for (k,v) in a if isempty(v)]
1-element Vector{Int64}:
 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
julia> filter(p->isempty(p.second), a)
Dict{Int64, Vector{T} where T} with 1 entry:
  6 => Any[]
```

`filter` takes a function as its first argument and can take a Dictionary as its second argument.

The function is given a `Pair` of key-value pairs, which has members `first` (the key) and `second` (the value). So here, we filter by an anonymous function that checks whether `p.second`, i.e. the value, `isempty`, and return only those `Pair`s where that returns true.

An equivalent, and perhaps better looking, way to do this is:

```
julia> filter(isempty∘last, a)
Dict{Int64, Vector{T} where T} with 1 entry:
  6 => Any[]
```

And for completeness' sake, if you want to just "check to see if" any of them are empty, you can take a `count` instead:

```
if count(isempty∘last, a) > 0
    dosomething()
end
```